# Looping Arrays to Change Background Image of Div

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, iteration

I am trying to create a loop of an array that changes the background of a div only one single loop.  The code is as follows;

```
var ImagesF = [];
ImagesF[0]="images/image1.png";
ImagesF[1]="images/image2.png";
ImagesF[2]="images/image3.png";

var i = 1;
var index = 0;
var iterations = 0;
var interval = setInterval(autoImgB(), 2000);

function autoImgB(arr1, id){
  var url = 'url(' + arr1 [i] + ')';
  if(index >= arr1.length) {
      index = 0;
      iterations++;
  }
  document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundImage = url;
      if (iterations >= 2) {
          clearInterval(interval);
      }  else {index++}
}
```

The code is being called like, `onclick="autoImgB(ImagesF, 'DIV')"`It seems to be trying to work and it does change the first image, however then it doesn't seem to be passing the arguments to the next iteration, what am I doing wrong?

-- UPDATE --

I have attempted to add the following code to pass the argument as originally passed during the function call `autoImgB(ImagesF, 'DIV')`, however I get an error that states, "arr1 is undefined".

```
var index = 0;
var iterations = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
autoImgB(arr1, id);
}, 2000);

function autoImgB(arr1, id){
  var url = 'url(' + arr1 [index] + ')';
  if(index >= arr1.length) {
    index = 0;
    iterations++;
  }
  document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundImage = url;
    if (iterations >= 2) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }  else {index++}
}
```

-- UPDATE 2 --

@Andy, requested that I post my nested DIV's for further help, the DIV structure within the contain are as depicted;

```js
var ImagesF = [];
ImagesF[0]="image1.png";
ImagesF[1]="image2.png";
ImagesF[2]="image3.png";

var n = 0;

function autoImgB(arr1) {
    var url = 'url(' + arr1 [n] + ')';
    if (n < arr1.length) {
 document.getElementById('DIV3').style.backgroundImage = url;
    setTimeout(autoImgB, 2000, arr1, ++n);
 console.log(url,n)
  }
}
```

```css
.DIV1{
    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-image:url('');
    background-color: none;
    display: none;
    z-index: 2;
}

.DIV2{
    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-image:url('');
    background-color: none;
    display: none;
    z-index: 1;
}

.DIV3{
 position:absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 417px;
    width:105px;
    height:130px;
 background-image:url('');
    background-color: none;
    display: block;
 z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
<div class="DIV1" id="DIV1"></div>
<div class="DIV2" id="DIV2"></div>
<div class="DIV3" id="DIV3"></div>
</div>

<button style="cursor:pointer" onclick="autoImgB(ImagesF)">Press</button>
```

What I would like for this to do is be able to call it by ID within the function, eg: autoImgB(ImagesF, 'DIV3').

Comment: Because you are passing in an array that doesn't exist. Try `autoImgB(ImagesF, id);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. So the main issue is that you are calling the function immediately rather than passing a reference to the function to `setInterval`.

```
 var interval = setInterval(autoImgB, 2000);
```

The other problem is that you aren't passing any arguments to the function. There are two ways to do that. The first is to pass them as additional arguments after the time:

```
var interval = setInterval(autoImgB, 2000, ImagesF, 0);
```

The second is to call the function itself within the `setInterval` callback:

```
var interval = setInterval(function () {
  autoImgB(ImagesF, 0);
}, 2000);
```

The other issue is that it's not clear what your HTML looks like. You appear to be getting an element with a particular `id` but are passing in `div` as the argument. So either you have an element like `<div id="div"></div>` or something else is going on. You should probably take a closer look at that.

That said you can shorten your code considerably if you use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`, as you only need to do the minimum of checks, and there's no need to clear the timer at any point. Just check to see if the index is less than the array length and call the function again.

```
var div = document.querySelector('div');

function autoImgB(arr, i) {
  if (i < arr.length) {
    div.style.backgroundImage = 'url("' + arr[i] + '")';
    setTimeout(autoImgB, 2000, arr, ++i);
  }
}

autoImgB(ImagesF, 0);
```

[Here's some working code](https://jsfiddle.net/wpebedbu/2/) with `setTimeout`.

Comment: Andy, this is a fantastic example, and exactly what I should have been doing from the start, I got too wrapped up in the setInterval function.  So to answer your question, YES, I am utilizing many DIV's within my HTML and calling them by <DIV id="DIV1"></DIV>, because this webpage is multi-layered I am hiding DIVs as necessary, this product is a small animation that cycles through DIV's.  Is there a way to specify the DIV within the function call, eg: autoImgB(ImagesF, 'DIV')??  The other thing is that this needs to be called upon an "onclick", not run automatically onload.

Comment: Well, you can use `querySelectorAll` to grab all the divs, and [then iterate over them like this](https://jsfiddle.net/wpebedbu/4/). That way you don't need the ids. If you add your nested divs to your question I'll have a better idea of what you're doing.

Comment: Well that's not exactly what I meant, but what I want to do is call the DIV in the onclick function so that I can re-use the code for other animations instead of creating a new function all together for specific DIV's.

Comment: You're talking about HTML, code and event listeners I can't see, so I can't help.

Comment: Andy, I have added the snippets so you can see a better picture of the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

setInterval expects a function as its first parameter

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
     autoImgB(ImagesF, 'DIV');
}, 2000);
```

Comment: This is great information.  The error I am receiving is saying that it is "Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference", which gives me the impression it is not passing the '(arr1, id)' originally passed in the function during the iteration.  I attempted to add this to the interval but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `setInterval(autoImgB(), 2000);` you aren't passing anything to the `autoImgB` function. Try passing the same values as you do inside of the `onclick` part

Comment: Seems like you are still facing a problem as you are passing `arr1` that doesn't exist, `arr1` is the parameter name of the function, when calling the function pass the array `ImageF` as the argument.

Comment: I am passing the correct, the OP is passing the arr1

Comment: Thank you Deepak, ztadic91 and @Andy, getting very close, it seems as though this script is now running onload instead of onclick.  Any advice?

Comment: because you are setting the interval directly, and not after some event

Answer (score 0):

The only thing which is wrong in the code you've created is that you pass the return value of the `autoImgB` function which is `undefined` into the `setInterval` function, but the `setInterval` function only accepts a `function` or a code `string`.

Documentation for [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)

I've created a [example](https://jsfiddle.net/eem64xqh/) based on your code to show you how it'll work.